# How can I split a getline() into array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have an input getline:
`man,meal,moon;fat,food,feel;cat,coat,cook;love,leg,lunch`

And I want to split this into an array when it sees a `;`, it can store all values before the `;` in an array.

For example:

`array[0]=man,meal,moon`

`array[1]=fat,food,feel`

And so on...

How can I do it? I tried many times but I failed!
Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With arrays it would be difficult, I would suggest looking up with Vectors and Stream.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c

Comment: If you know the number of elements in the array before hand then you can use an `array` or `std::array`. But if you only know the size at runtime you should be using `std::vector` (it is a resizable array).

Comment: I know it's difficult by arrays, but i have a great project and i need arrays to quick doing the next steps

Comment: Why do you think vector is slow?

Comment: i didn't try to use vector before, do you think it will be useful?

Comment: The `std::vector` is probably the most used container in C++. It is as fast as the built in array with the additional benefit that it is resizeable. You see raw arrays used very seldomly in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::stringstream` and `std::getline`.

I also suggest that you use `std::vector` as it's resizeable.

In the example below, we get input line and store it into a `std::string`, then we create a `std::stringstream` to hold that data. And you can use `std::getline` with `;` as delimiter to store the string data between the semicolon into the variable `word` as seen below, each "word" which is pushed back into a vector:

```
int main()
{
    string line;
    string word;
    getline(cin, line);
    stringstream ss(line);

    vector<string> vec;
    while (getline(ss, word, ';')) {
        vec.emplace_back(word);
    }

    for (auto i : vec) // Use regular for loop if you can't use c++11/14
        cout << i << '\n';
```

Alternatively, if you can't use `std::vector`:

```
string arr[256];
int count = 0;
while (getline(ss, word, ';') && count < 256) {
    arr[count++] = word;
}
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://rextester.com/live/NAN16898)</kbd>

Outputs:

```
man,meal,moon
fat,food,feel
cat,coat,cook
love,leg,lunch
```

Comment: wow, it works! thanks so much. And if i want to take "man,fat,cat,love" in one another array and also "meal,food,coat,leg" "moon,cook,lunch" ... Can i use the same code with a "for loop" for array?